# How to change the value in JS from one function to other

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, replace

I an here having one array with some value and one string and what I need is if any value from an array get match in string it should replace the matched string with empty. Now I am doing this in function I was assuming of callback value but I don't know what I did wrong.

Attaching the code below

```
async function ok (){

var arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
var addressLine = 'This is one'

const ans = await matchAndRemove(arr, addressLine)

console.log(`This is address ${addressLine}`) 
// Out put is 'This is address This is one' but here I expect the output as 'This is'
console.log(`This is match ${ans}`) // Output is 'This is match one'
}

const matchAndRemove = (arr, addressLine) => {

    for (var val of arr) {
        if (addressLine.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
            const match = addressLine.match(new RegExp(val, 'ig')).join(' ');
            addressLine = addressLine.replace(new RegExp(val, 'ig'), '');
            console.log(addressLine) // Output is 'This is'
            return match;
        }
    }

}

ok()
```

Any suggestions to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function cannot change `addressLine` because JavaScript does not have call-by-reference (moreover, strings are immutable). If you want a modified value for that string, you could (also) return it.

So return both the match and the new value for `addressLine`. You can return it as a pair (an array). The caller can destructure that pair back into separate variables.

NB: there is no need for `await` as there is no asynchronous API involved

Correction:

```js
function ok (){
    var arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
    var addressLine = 'This is one'

    // Get two returns by destructuring
    const [newAddressLine, ans] = matchAndRemove(arr, addressLine)

    console.log("newAddressLine:", newAddressLine) // 'This is'
    console.log("ans:", ans) // 'one'
}

const matchAndRemove = (arr, addressLine) => {
    for (var val of arr) {
        if (addressLine.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
            const match = addressLine.match(new RegExp(val, 'ig')).join(' ');
            addressLine = addressLine.replace(new RegExp(val, 'ig'), '');
            return [addressLine, match]; // Return both as a pair
        }
    }
}

ok()
```

Not your question, but it is probably more interesting to use *one* regular expression instead of an array of words that you need to check one by one:

```js
const arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
const regex = RegExp("\\b(" + arr.join("|") + ")\\b\\s*", "gi"); // One regex for all

var addressLine = 'This is one';

// One replace call will replace all words in arr
const result = addressLine.replace(regex, "").trim();
console.log("result:", result) // 'This is'

// If you wanted to know the matches:
const matched = addressLine.match(regex);
console.log("matched:", matched);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is returning the value of match inside for loop. That's why the function is closing after first match is found . You should store the the matches in an array and then join them to get the final result.
Try this :

```
async function ok() {
  var arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
  var addressLine = 'This is one';

  const ans = await matchAndRemove(arr, addressLine);

  console.log(`This is address ${addressLine}`); // Output is 'This is'
  console.log(`This is match ${ans}`); // Output is 'This is match one'
}

const matchAndRemove = (arr, addressLine) => {
  let matches = [];

  for (var val of arr) {
    if (addressLine.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
      matches.push(val);
      addressLine = addressLine.replace(new RegExp(val, 'ig'), '');
    }
  }

  return matches.join(' ');
};

ok();
```